# How to use OpenCV to process image so that the text become sharp and clear?

Tags: android, opencv

Wanted to achieve something like this: http://www.leptonica.com/binarization.html

While searching for solutions, most of the answers were general instructions such as advise to look at adaptive filter, gaussian blur, dilation and erosion but none of them provide any sample code to start with (so can play around with the values)..

I know different image require different methods and values to achieve optimum clarity, but I just need some general filter so that the image at least slightly sharper and less noisy compare to the original, before doing any OCR on it.

this is what I've tried so far..

```
Mat imageMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(photo, imageMat);
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageMat, imageMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 4);
```

but being an image processing newb, obviously I don't know what I'm doing XD

original image:
[image: original image]

after applying the above:
[image: image after applying filters]

How to do it correctly?

UPDATE: got it much closer thanks to metsburg, berak and Aurelius

Using the medianBlur method since cvSmooth with CV_MEDIAN is deprecated and replaced with medianBlur:

```
Imgproc.medianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, 3);
Imgproc.threshold(imageMat, imageMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Result:
[image: using medianblur before applying otsu]

Using back the GaussianBlur method, the result actually is slightly better:

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
Imgproc.threshold(imageMat, imageMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Result:
[image: using gaussianblur before applying otsu]

For this image the difference is not noticable, so I tried another image which is a photo taken off the computer screen. Computer screen gives a lot of noises (wavy lines) so it is very hard to remove the noise.

Example original image:
[image: pcscreen original image]

Directly applying otsu:
[image: pcscreen directly apply otsu]

using medianBlur before otsu:
[image: pcscreen using medianBlur before applying otsu]

using GaussianBlur before otsu:
[image: pcscreen using GaussianBlur before applying otsu]

Seems like gaussian blur is slightly better, however I'm still playing with the settings..
If anyone can advise on how to improve the computer screen photo further, please, let us know :)
One more thing.. using this method on the image inside the top link yields horrible results :( see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju73J.jpg

Comment: How did you get the output image? As in the local image we convert in mat format but from img.proc how to see the output image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you're almost there. Just try these modifications:

Instead of

```
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
```

try:

```
     cvSmooth(imageMat, imageMat, CV_MEDIAN, new Size(3, 3), 0);
```

*check the syntax, may not exactly match*

The link you posted uses thresholding of Otsu, so try this:

```
 Imgproc.threshold(imageMat, imageMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

for thresholding.

Try tweaking the parameters here and there, you should get something pretty close to your desired outcome.

Comment: there's nothing to tweak with THRESH_OTSU, that's another "automatic" method

Comment: well, it should work that way. the problem is, I see a lot of noise in the final image you posted in the question... so I was suggesting you tweak the cvSmooth parameters to achieve a less noisy result. that should eliminate the grains from the final image. and alter the high and low value in your threshold function, thats should swap the black and white channels, which gives you approximately the same result as the link you provided.

Comment: yes, you are right @Aurelius : it needs to be Imgproc.threshold(imageMat, imageMat, low, high, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

Comment: @metsburg If you edit your question to correct it, I'll upvote. I just tried Otsu after Gaussian blurring; it works quite well.

Comment: Wow thanks for the responses, you guys are awesome! I've just formatted my PC so I'll need to reinstall Eclipse and all the android library so I could probably only able to try these tomorrow.. sorry didn't check back earlier because usually my questions don't get much response so just trying my luck this time :) Also, where did you all learn these THRESH_OTSU, threshold and adaptive threshold terminology? Since my maths is not good, when reading the OpenCV tutorial can't understand the maths equation XD

Comment: Just tried these and it works!! Though cvSmooth is deprecated and replaced with Blur, GaussianBlur, MedianBlur and bilateralFilter. Since you suggested CV_MEDIAN so I guess the equivalent is MedianBlur :) Updated question with results and findings!

Comment: 1. the strategies for processing images captured from computer screen and printed text will be significantly different, 2. one technique/methodology will not give optimal result in both these two cases, 3. if you're using the camera of a mobile device, there is nothing (in my knowledge so far) you can do to reduce the noise to a level which is significantly lesser than what you've already done. However, there can be a workaround. If you can grab consecutive frames from a video, you'll notice that these striations/wavy lines tend to shift around rapidly, but the text doesn't(within 5-7 frames).

Comment: You can use this property to build a probability density of the pixels, wherein you should get a higher average probability of the text pixels than the non-text pixels. This should be pretty effective filtering if implemented properly. However, not having done this practically, I can't assure you of the level of difficulty /effectiveness of the output with this approach. I hope someone else can help you better.

Comment: Thanks metsburg! It is ok the main application is on printed text, and not for computer screen so don't need to worry :) But now there's an issue where the quality is very bad when there's dark areas in the paper area, for example the original: http://imgur.com/bWvsW77 after enhancing it looks like this: http://imgur.com/Sy3fTJe with a dark patch. Any advice on how to make it better? (I know I'm pushing it XD actually I'm already very happy at what we achieved so far^^)
I heard about some algorithm that can process each block individually, do you know how it is done?

Comment: Can't really say without experimenting... on top of my head, I think you may try going back to adaptive threshold with median blur. Instead of Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, use Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY. I'll let you know more details as I find out.

Comment: I can do the experimenting :) Just let me know what to try. Though I do think that at some point I will need to learn more on these stuff - THRESH_BINARY, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THREST_OTSU all of these are alien to me and I'm just shooting blindly. Where is a good place to start?

Comment: to find out more about openCV's implementation of image processing, willow garage should suffice: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html.

Comment: For a more mathematical foundation of image processing, try taking up a course or something... you may try these links: http://www.tnw.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Faculteit/TNW/Over_de_faculteit/Afdelingen/Imaging_Science_and_Technology/Research/Research_Groups/Quantitative_Imaging/Publications/List_Publications/doc/FIP2.2.pdf,  http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/downloads/tutorials/fip.pdf,  http://www.etf.ucg.ac.me/Digital%20image%20processing.pdf

Comment: Thanks, still struggling with adaptive threshold and couldn't get it right though

Comment: This seem to work pretty well:
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageMat, imageMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 10);

Depending on the image, one might need to adjust the block size and constant to a certain degree to achieve better results.

Using the image from before..
Original: http://imgur.com/bWvsW77
Enhanced: http://imgur.com/TpFqzkr

Comment: that looks pretty good, yes the block size depends on the image size.

Comment: hello sir me use for your library remove unwanted object for image but in this lib vert high wait then result find so please let me know how to solve out this problem ..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV` use `Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY` only as _INV is inverting your image after binarisations and resulted is the said output shown above in your example.

correct code:

```
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageMat, imageMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 4);
```

Comment: what is imageMat?